# Drive replaced in RAID5 not automatically syncing, instead showing as spare

Tags: raid, raid5

Replacing the drives in a RAID5. `sdb` failed, replaced it. Things went well. Now I'm replacing `sda`, but after being added to the array it shows as a spare and doesn't sync.

Steps followed:

1. `mdadm --manage /dev/md127 --fail /dev/sda1`.
2. `mdadm --manage /dev/md127 --remove /dev/sda1`.
3. Turn off system. Replace `sda` drive.
4. Partition as gpt using `parted` with raid flag.
5. `mdadm --manage /dev/md127 --add /dev/sda1`.
6. `cat proc/mdstat` to check that we're syncing. We're not.

I can't figure out why we're not syncing. Any help would be appreciated. Output is shown below.

RAID details:

```
[me@me /]# mdadm --detail /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
        Version : 1.1
  Creation Time : Mon Oct 22 16:20:37 2012
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 1953518592 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 976759296 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Mon Nov  7 18:33:10 2016
          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

  Delta Devices : 1, (3->4)

           Name : meme:0
           UUID : 28cf18b6:b05b9701:5d28754b:c387cb95
         Events : 247368

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       3       8       49        0      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       2       0        0        2      removed
       4       8       33        2      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       6       8       17        3      active sync   /dev/sdb1

       5       8        1        -      spare   /dev/sda1
```

MD stat:

```
[me@me /]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md127 : active raid5 sda1[5](S) sdc1[4] sdd1[3] sdb1[6]
      1953518592 blocks super 1.1 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/3] [U_UU]
      bitmap: 4/8 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

**Update**

There is data on the RAID. It's currently mounted and being used. I don't mind disabling it while I'm replacing the drives, but I'd like to preserve the data on the array.

**Update**

Worked around the headache. `rsync`ed the contents of the degraded array to a backup drive, replaced the RAID with fresh-baked drives, then `rsync`ed back. In the process, we learned the value of scheduling automated incremental backups (as opposed to the schedule being based on "Hey when was the last time we backed up the system? Oh God do it now!")

Comment: duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/676638/mdadm-drive-replacement-shows-up-as-spare-and-refuses-to-sync

Comment: @IporSircer Tried that solution. Did not work. My `sync_action` file reads '"idle"

Comment: in worst case you can recreate the array: http://www.kossboss.com/sparetoactive (be careful!)

Comment: I never use `--manage`, and it's not mentioned in my manpage. Try removing the device: `mdadm /dev/md127 -f /dev/sda1 -r /dev/sda1`, clearing the metadata: `mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda1` and adding it again: `mdadm /dev/md127 -a /dev/sda1`

Comment: yes, as @wurtel said you have to clean the superblock. After that re-adding should do the trick.

Comment: @wurtel I'm a bit new to this, but wouldn't clearing the metadata lead to the data on the array being unrecoverable? In hindsight, I realize I should've mentioned the drives aren't empty. Added it to the question now.

Comment: @Mirov sda disk haven't any data. Don't afraid clear it before it will be joined to the array. If that disk was used in other RAID it has RAID metadata witch doesn't allow use it in new array. You need to clean only sda.

Comment: What Mikhail said... you stated that sda was replaced, i.e. contains NO data. I never mentioned any drive besides sda!

Comment: @wurtel That's a good point. Overlooked that. Thanks guys. I'll try that tonight.

Comment: @wurtel No effect. Will keep searching.